# Question Python task's(created from coroutine) implementation and concurrent semantics

Tags: python, coroutine

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await say_after(1, 'hello')
    await say_after(2, 'world')

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

output:

```
started at 17:13:52
hello
world
```

finished at 17:13:55

```py
async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(1, 'hello'))

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(2, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    # Wait until both tasks are completed (should take
    # around 2 seconds.)
    await task1
    await task2

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

Note that expected output now shows that the snippet runs 1 second faster than before:
output:

```
started at 17:14:32
hello
world
finished at 17:14:34
```

I know that coroutine has only one operating system thread, and yield control over to another coroutine,so there's no race condition on multiple coroutine for modifying same data structure, but how does asyncio implement task, to make it possible to run task concurrently?
Also are there sync issues? (That is, one task accesses and modifies a data structure, while another task accesses and modifies the data structure at the same time,
Will it has sync issue and corrupt the data structure?)